# Once a week pulse out of small circuit for slow clock?

Tags: arduino, clock

I have a clock (a regular quartz clock), that I want to go very slowly. I want it to tick 60 times a year.

I disconnected the internal chip and hooked up an arduino to do the counting, and every 525948.76 seconds it tells the clock to tick. This works fine, but using an arduino is overkill.

How cheap and simple could I make this "pulse every 525948.76 seconds"-device that would replace the arduino? It would not need to be as precise a timekeeper as an arduino.

(this person did the same thing and explained how to
http://www.cibomahto.com/2008/03/controlling-a-clock-with-an-arduino/)

Comment: How precise do you need this to be? There are very simple timer circuits, but in the long run, they may not be very accurate. One option could be to make a crystal oscillator and use a quartz crustal plus some counters to do what you want.

Comment: Precise enough that in a year, the clock second-hand has moved 360 degrees.

Comment: I mean, how exact do you want year to be? As is 31 536 000.0000000000 seconds or would few hundreds/tens of seconds up or down be important?

Comment: A few hundreds of seconds would matter all that much.

Comment: Well if they do matter, then I don' think that you can get things better in a simpler way than they are now. Best bet would be probably to try to optimize away the Arduino itself and move to less capable and cheaper microcontroller while carefully designing its clock system, so that it is as precise as possible.

Comment: I'm sorry, a few hundred seconds would NOT matter all that much.

Comment: I assume you'll need something that would run on a battery for more that a year as you won't be able to 'set' the clock midway, would you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a high precision timing function, consider using a real time clock with an integrated Temperature Compensated Crystal Oscillator (TCXO). An example is the [Maxim DS3231 RTC](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS3231.pdf) with TCXO, available from eBay for [under $3 a pair](http://www.ebay.com/itm/2PCS-DS3231SN-3231-IC-RTC-W-TCXO-16-SOIC-NEW-GOOD-QUALITY-R2-/300928146359?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4610b71bb7) including international shipping.

This gives you some advantages over the crystal oscillators used on Arduino boards:

- Accuracy of 3.5 parts per million, i.e. 110.45 seconds of drift per year.
- Simplicity of counting time - you can set up the part to output a 1024 Hz square wave, for 0.977 millisecond precision for your clock ticks - or a once-per-second interrupt if you do not need the second decimal precision of ticking mentioned in the question
- The inbuilt calendar allows a recalibration of start time every year, including leap years

To interface with such an RTC, you can use a very minimal microcontroller with an inbuilt RC oscillator, such as the ATtiny family.

The device thus would need merely the battery, the minimal microcontroller, the RTC chip, a few resistors and some decoupling capacitors, not much else I can think of - making it both inexpensive, and really simple to build.

On a home-etched PCB, the entire device could be built in under an inch square, for perhaps $6 or so in singles, will run from a single button cell battery for years, and deliver an accuracy far beyond what any Arduino can do out of the box. A TCXO by itself would cost as much or more in single units.

If you chose to build a few dozen of these, cost could be dropped down to well under $3 apiece including professionally etched PCBs with pretty silkscreen and resist layer.

**Code**:

- The microcontroller uses I2C to set up the RTC for either 1 Hz or 1024 Hz output
- An interrupt enabled pin on the MCU is triggered at each pulse set above, and counts duration - the microcontroller is set to low power sleep mode the rest of the time.
- On achieving a count of 525948.76 seconds, or 525949 seconds if you are not fussy, the microcontroller pulses your external quartz clock.
- Once a a month, or annually, the microcontroller retrieves the actual date and time from the RTC, and corrects for any drift due to the 525949 second rounding off

Answer (score 1):

For long-term frequency stability, the electrical power grid is pretty good. It provides a 60Hz timebase that is still used for many clocks. This [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility_frequency#Long-term_stability_and_clock_synchronization) discusses how the powerline frequency is adjusted to maintain a constant 50/60Hz.

The main problem is power outages, but at least in US metropolitan areas, these are rare. If you are willing to accept the small possibility that power may go out at some point, then a 120V/5V transformer, a rectifier and some counter chips will probably suffice. The transformer and rectifier will provide a 60Hz pulse around 5 volts. Instead of counter chips, I'd probably opt for a small microcontroller to take those pulses and do the math to pulse once a week. However, this can also be done with discrete logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a small microcontroller with a hardware rel-time clock (RTC). Most of them allow you to program an alarm. So set the alarm for 525948.76 seconds into the future, and put the processor core to sleep. When the RTC time matches the alarm time, the RTC will generate an interrupt and wake up the processor. At that point, your code runs again. Advance the clock hands, set the RTC alarm to 525948.76 seconds into the future, and put the processor to sleep again. (Or, calculate what 525948.76 seconds from midnight Jan. 1 is, and reset the clock/calendar to midnight Jan. 1 every time and use the same alarm time.)

Many many many micros have hardware RTC peripherals. Unfortunately, the parametric search on Microchip's website doesn't seem to allow me to filter by the presence of an RTC. (My gut suspicion is that Microchip is likely to have the cheapest part with a hardware RTC.

Microchip also has an application note on how to do the same thing using Timer1 on chips that don't have an RTC module: http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1824&appnote=en011057. That's probably as "cheap and simple" as you're likely to find. Spend a few more pennies on a crystal with as much accuracy as you can find. +/- 10 ppm is 315 seconds/year, I believe, or a little more than 5 minutes. If you keep your clock at room temperature you're quite likely to see better performance than that.

Comment: How accurate/inaccurate is the arduino?

Comment: @user1081813 The older Arduino boards, using the AVR microcontrollers (e.g. ATmega238) and an inexpensive crystal, are not very precise at all. The newer Arduino Due, with the ARM microcontroller and a somewhat better crystal, is more accurate. The constraint is the accuracy of the crystal, not the microcontroller. What you need is a cesium clock chip, or at least a baked TCXO instead of the crystal, for relatively accurate timing.